# Python/ElementTree: Parsing inline elements w/ respect to surrounding text?

Tags: python, text, elementtree

I need to parse some XML containing *inline* elements. The XML look, for example, like this:

`<section>
Fubar, I'm so fubar, fubar and even more <fref bar="baz">fubare</fref>. And yet more fubar.
</section>`

If I iterate now over this structure with `for elem in list(parent): ...` I only get access to fref. If I now process fref, the surrounding text is of course lost, since text isn't  a real element.

Does anybody know of a way to properly address this issue?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Do you want to strip the tag and leave all the text?

Comment: I need to actually parse that thing. It's a bit like HTMLs a-tag, which is replaced in-line, without interrupting text. I think I need to iterate over child elements *and* text "elements" at the same time & retain their order. So "Fubar, I'm so fubar...." is processed, then the fref-tag, then the text after that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following shows how to achieve this with `lxml`.

```py
>>> from lxml.etree import fromstring
>>> tree = fromstring('''<section> Fubar, I'm so fubar, fubar and even more <fref bar="baz">fubare</fref>. And yet more fubar. </section>''')
>>> elem = tree.xpath('/section/fref')[0]
>>> elem.text
'fubare'
>>> elem.tail
'. And yet more fubar. '
>>> elem.getparent().text
" Fubar, I'm so fubar, fubar and even more "
```

From `lxml.etree` [tutorial](http://lxml.de/tutorial.html#elements-contain-text):

> If you want to read only the text, i.e. without any intermediate tags,
>   you have to recursively concatenate all text and tail attributes in
>   the correct order. Again, the tostring() function comes to the rescue,
>   this time using the method keyword:

```py
>>> from lxml.etree import tostring
>>> tostring(html, method="text")
" Fubar, I'm so fubar, fubar and even more fubare. And yet more fubar. "
```

There's also an XPath way to do this, it's described in the linked page.

Comment: That is exactly what I want to achieve, but unfortunately I cannot install additional packages.

Comment: `xml.etree` is different in that elements don't have a `getparent()` method, so I think you'll have to access the text from the parent element directly.